# Ecto or Elixir datatype that maps to MySql BIGINT

Tags: mysql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm new to Elixir and Phoenix (6 months learning), I have a situation where I want to assign an Ecto model's field (not primary key or table ID) to BIGINT in MySql.

I realize when you create an Ecto model, the ID of that model in MySql table would automatically mapped to **BIGINT** after migration.

After checking this [site](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html), I tried to create an Ecto model's field to **:integer** or **:id** in both model and its corresponding migration script but it always gives me **INT** datatype in MySql.

Anybody knows what datatype in Elixir or Ecto that corresponds to BIGINT in MySql, so when I execute the migration script my table will have that particular column as BIGINT?

Thanks

Comment: Try the type `:bigint` in the migration and `:integer` in the schema.

Comment: @Dogbert, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The type in the migration should be the actual database type and in the schema it should be the type you want in Elixir. Since Elixir supports arbitrary precision integers, all integer types in databases are usually mapped to the native `:integer` type. So what you want is to use the `:bigint` type in the migration and `:integer` in the schema.

```
create table(:foos) do
  add :bar, :bigint
end

<!-- -->

schema "foos" do
  field :bar, :integer
end
```

Comment: This is great when you have write-read access of the database. How would go about when you only have read access of  the database (say, a legacy project)?

Comment: @Sebastialonso, in that case you wouldn't have the migration and the database column in question would already be **BIGINT**, right? So you'd just use the latter part of the answer.