# bigint versus integer error in Ecto with Legacy database

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, biginteger, ecto

I'm in the following situation: There's a PostgreSQL legacy database from a Rails application I need to interact with.

Phoenix is using Repo with a schema to connect to that database, and so far it seems to work OK, I can retrieve elements and perform some basic queries with the expected results.

Now, I started playing with some advance queries, and I'm getting some issues that I don't how to solve. For example:

`from(is in acc, or_where: ^current_user.id in [is.transcriber_id, is.radiologist_id, is.validator_id])`

returns the following error

```
** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR 42P08 (ambiguous_parameter): inconsistent types deduced for parameter $2

bigint versus integer
    (ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:431: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.execute_and_cache/7
    (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/queryable.ex:133: Ecto.Repo.Queryable.execute/5
    (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/queryable.ex:37: Ecto.Repo.Queryable.all/4
```

After some research, I discovered that ActiveRecord in Rails, stores integers as `bigints` but I'm not sure Postgrex or Ecto (I really don't who is in charge of this) is interpreting correctly the integer `current_user.id` I'm using in the query.

I have the feeling that the expression `in [is.transcriber_id, is.radiologist_id, is.validator_id]` is a bit greedy and maybe I should go with fragments.

**UPDATE**:

`is` stands for ImagingStudy. The Rails migration of this model is as follows:

```rb
class CreateImagingStudies < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :imaging_studies do |t|
      t.string :status_name
      t.bigint :validator_id
      t.bigint :radiologist_id
      t.bigint :transcriber_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

The Phoenix schema for manipulating the table corresponding to the imaging_studies is as follows

```
defmodule Worklist.Studies.ImagingStudy do
  use Ecto.Schema

  schema "imaging_studies" do
    field :transcriber_id, :integer
    field :radiologist_id, :integer
    field :validator_id, :integer

    timestamps(inserted_at: :created_at, updated_at: :updated_at)
  end
```

There's no schema for users, since they are managed in another service. Consider the `current_user` a map with an integer field named `id`.

Comment: Could you please show schemas and migrations for both `users` and `is` (whatever `is` is.) They should be declared as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45400665/ecto-or-elixir-datatype-that-maps-to-mysql-bigint).

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin information added. Thanks! Remember that the legacy Rails application was the one in charge of the migrations, Phoenix can only read from the database.

Comment: Would not `type(^current_user.id, :integer)` instead of `^current_user.id` help (see [`Ecto.Query.API.type/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html?#type/2))?

Comment: Intriguing I'll try it and report back. There's an issue in my mind with that, given that the original field is a bigint (i.e. arbitrary precision integer) and what you suggest is effectually casting the arbitrary precision into a non-arbitrary precision number, couldn't that lead to future problems with big enough numbers?

Comment: Nope, Ecto’s `:integer` is explicitly mapped to Postgres’ `:bigint`. See e.g. [here](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/v2.2.10/lib/ecto/adapters/postgres/connection.ex#L532).

Comment: Yes, a further reading proved that I'm an idiot.

Comment: Wow, wow, take it easy, you are not and let’s see if it indeed works :)

Comment: It worked! Thanks. If you can put that into an answer, I will kindly accept it

Comment: Always welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Ecto* voluntarily [explicitly maps](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/v2.2.10/lib/ecto/adapters/postgres/connection.ex#L532) `:integer` type to Postgres’ `:bigint`.

That said, by using [`Ecto.Query.API.type/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html?#type/2) one might explicitly cast the parameter to `:bigint` to help [ecto](/questions/tagged/ecto) with proper type mapping:

```
from(
  is in acc,
  or_where:
    type(^current_user.id, :integer) in [
      is.transcriber_id, is.radiologist_id, is.validator_id
    ]
)
```

Comment: This [remains true](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto_sql/blob/6f55dd721d19819d047013af2671d3a24b66f24a/lib/ecto/adapters/postgres/connection.ex#L753) as of `ecto_sql` 3.7.2. 